# The named parameter 'name' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

The named parameter 'name' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'name'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigation/screen2.dart';

class Screenone extends StatelessWidget {
const Screenone({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  // navigation to next page.
  /*body: 
Column(children: [
    Text("Screen one"),
    ElevatedButton(
      
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) {
              return Screentwo();
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Text("Go to next page"),
    )
  ]),*/
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('person $index'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Screentwo(name: 'person $index');
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: ((context, index) {
          return Divider();
        }),
        itemCount: 20),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Share the code for Screentwo.

Comment: Named parameters are written a bit differently. When defining the function, wrap any named parameters in curly braces ({ }). This line defines a function with named parameters: ScreenTwo({required String name}) , final String name;

Answer (score 2):

To be able to pass a parameter to from X page to Screentwo you must ask for a parameter from Screentwo in the first place;

```
class Screentwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  const Screentwo({Key? key, required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //return your widget
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the optional name parameter in ScreenTwo.

```dart
class ScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? name;
  const ScreenTwo({Key? key, this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(name ?? ""),
    );
  }
}
```

Call Example:

```
return Screentwo(name: 'person name');

or 

return Screentwo();
```