# The named parameter isn't defined.[flutter]

Tags: flutter

I want to convey int value '10' from 'tmpWidget' class to 'CakeTimerUI' class.
So I made some code like this.

This is my CakeTimerUI code:

```
class CakeTimerUI extends StatefulWidget {

  final int value2;

  const CakeTimerUI({super.key, required this.value2});



  @override
  CakeTimerState createState() => CakeTimerState();
}

class CakeTimerState extends State<CakeTimerUI> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TimerFunction(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and I called it from tmpWidget like this:

```
class tmpWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final int value1;

  const tmpWidget({super.key, required this.value1});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    double screenWidth = mediaQueryData.size.width;
    double screenHeight = mediaQueryData.size.height;
    return Container(
      width: screenWidth / 3 - screenWidth * 0.01,
      height: screenHeight / 2 - screenWidth * 0.01,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
    child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      const CakeTimerUI(value2: 10),
      Text('Value: $value1', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
      ],
    ),
    
    );
  }
}
```

[But I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKpX8.png)

What should I have to do with this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The named parameter 'name' isn't defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73397828/the-named-parameter-name-isnt-defined)

Comment: I tried to change cakeTimerUI constructor like this: "const CakeTimerUI({Key? key, required this.value2}) : super(key: key);" but It still no working.

Comment: Do you happen to have two separate CakeTimerUI classes and you are importing the wrong one? Because I recreated it locally and your code works.

Comment: hmm... It`s strange. I was running my code in vscode. But with your advice, I changed program into android studio. now It`s working without error. anyway I could solve my problem thanks to you. @tomerpacific @Mayur Mahajan